# Game GUI framework

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am currently in the process of re-touching the user interface of a game ([OpenLieroX](http://www.openlierox.net) namely). I am looking for a library/framework that would allow an easy GUI creation. To be concrete, these are my requirements:

- **Open source** - the game is LGPL and running into license issues is the last thing we want to care about :)
- **Cross platform** - at least Linux/Unix, Mac OS X and Windows 2k+ are a must but more is better.
- **Stable and mature** - I would prefer not using a project that will die in a month
- **Fast and lightweight** (less than 15 mb compiled) - it's for a game after all
- **C++ interface** - the game is written in C++
- **Easy to use** - tutorials and a good documentation are a big plus
- **Easily adjustable** - it should be easy to change the appearance of widgets
- **An easy to use styling language** - a simple language that designers can use to create appealing skins for the game
- **An easy way to add custom widgets** - I need to add viewports, character skins etc. to the interface and render them my way
- **Support for off-screen rendering** (into a buffer)

I have already tried these libraries:

- **Webkit** (various ports) - it's cool but not really made for game GUIs. Impossible to add custom elements with custom drawing (viewports etc.).
- **Enlightenment** - cool libraries but too Linux centric. Especially the Windows port is incomplete.
- **Qt** - great but offscreen rendering doesn't belong to its strenghts and mainly it's too big for the purpose
- **GTK** - quite the same problems as with Qt, poor Mac OS X support

I would highly appreciate if anyone knows a framework that could fit these needs. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Crazy Eddie's GUI System for Games](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? I'm pretty sure it meets *most* of your requirements.

Comment: That's it. It actually meets all of my requirements plus some more I haven't even thought of :)

Comment: We HATE cegui, and just recently moved on to flash (in hindsight HTML5 would have been better though)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best GUI for a game is [guichan](http://guichan.sourceforge.net/). It has all the *features* you are looking for.

Comment: That looks pretty cool, thanks. I only can't seem to find any scripting language for defining the layouts. I want the designers to be able to change the GUI without recompiling the game (they are not programmers after all) and writing my own seems like a too much hassle to do properly.

Comment: @dark_charlie: I'm quite sure it's possible to play around with guichan using LUA and to define GUIs in XML. See [xmlguichan](http://code.google.com/p/xmlguichan/) or [GCE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gce/).

Comment: That GUI definition in XML looks nice, even though it might get messy with more complex layouts. After reading the tutorials, I've decided to give CEGUI the first chance to prove its usefulness.