# How do i create an interface for C Game

Tags: c, linux, windows, interface

I just created the "Hangman game" using C language, i used GCC to compile it and worked in the terminal.

Let's say that i started with C a week ago, and this is the only programming language i know (Html & CSS arn't programming languages even if i know them). I'm a complete beginner so.

My question is, from the code source i have, how can i create an interface, an app that i'd start on windows (instead of linux terminal), with "buttons" or something like that ?
If i can't do this from the code source, what wold u recommend ?
What would be the software i should use instead of visual studio code to write code (because i guess i'll need a specific software if i want an interface or if i want to compile it in order to ceate a windows app ?)

I'm not english native so i may did some languages mistakes, sorry in advance.
Let me know if i can be more precise and explain something using other words.

Comment: Try GTK. Or GTK with Glade.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/

Comment: If you're using Microsoft products, I'm sure you have access to [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). Using WinAPI makes your program not portable to other OSes though.

Comment: @michi Seems it's a bit realy complicated to install '-'

Comment: @jaybird Are you sure Unity allow to create such mini-games ? If so is there a place i can find specific help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous libraries and frameworks which can provide a GUI for your games.

- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)
- [Dear IMGUI](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui)
- [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/) with [widgets](http://members.chello.nl/w.boeke/SDL-widgets/index.html)
- and many more, depending on your requirements

Related posts:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/what-c-gui-library-can-you-suggest
- [Game GUI framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845969/game-gui-framework)
- http://samirsinha.com/choosing-a-gui-framework/

It's probably best to study existing games and how they are designed, what libraries people use, and so on, before embarking on building your own from scratch.

Also try reading some of the resources in the [GameDev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Seems they arn't free. I'll take a look at their tryal version.. As i's just for train myself, i don't see the goal on paying for a software u_u